# rxjs fire parallel requests and wait until both complete and update after one of them emits

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs5

My requirements are that I have two endpoints one to listing of HondaCars and one to listing of PeugoetCars When I use the `combineLatest` operator it doesn't wait for the other stream to complete;

here my requirements => first time wait until both source streams receive a value then after that refresh after one of both receives a value

**EDIT**

So after some time of searching, I just sticked with `combineLatest` but the trick was here:

```
this.loading = Observable.combineLatest(
  myFirstObservableIndicatingIfFirstHttpReqEnded,
  mySecondObservableIndicatingIfSecondHttpReqEnded
).map(d => d.some(t => t === true));
```

so now, the user just sees the spinner until all requests have been completed even if one of both observables already emited some value.

Just to clarify I have two loadingReducers that that handle the loading logic for each observable, so in my case I did this to know when both http calls completed

Comment: Complete has a very specific meaning with observables. A marble diagram would make your situation clearer. Anyway, it sounds like what you want is in fact `combineLatest`: "To ensure output array has always the same length, `combineLatest` will actually wait for all input observables to emit at least once"

Comment: could you update your question with what you already tried?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo ok, i'll update my question with what I did

Answer (score 2):

You need to first use `Observable.forkJoin()`, and then use a `.switchMap()` to switch your observable to `Observable.combineLatest()`:

```
let combined = Observable
    .forkJoin([myFirstObservableIndicatingIfFirstHttpReqEnded, mySecondObservableIndicatingIfSecondHttpReqEnded])
    .switchMap(joinedResults => {
        console.log('forkJoined results!', joinedResults);
        this.hasReqEnded = joinedResults.some(t => t === true);
        return Observable.combineLatest(joinedResults)
    });

combined.subscribe(d => this.hasReqEnded = d.some(t => t === true));
```

***Note***: `this.hasReqEnded` is just some dummy variable I created. The trick is that you need to write the values of `this.hasReqEnded` twice : Once at the switchMap (after the forkJoin), and the other one at the subscribe, which is after the `Observable.combineLastest()`.

Alternatively you can have two observables : One being the `forkJoin`, and the other one `combineLatest()`, and you can subscribe to the two Observables and update your variable accordingly.

Here's a [working JSBin](https://jsbin.com/fokatecivo/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Http call is finite stream: it emit value and completed.
So, first part: "first time wait until both source streams receive a value "

```
const initial$ = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
   this.httpService1.get(),
   this.httpService2.get()
);
```

Second part: "after that refresh after one of both receives a value".

We need to transform some infinite stream (some user action, for example) to stream of 'HondaCars' or 'PeugoetCars', it can be done by ".switchMap":

```
const stream1$ = someUserAction1$
  .switchMap(()=>this.httpService1.get());
```

So, if we want to have a stream of <[HondaCars, PeugoetCars]> that emit immediately and after some action:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  someUserAction1$
      .startWith(null) // we need to make initial call, but we have no user action yet, fix it )
      .switchMap(()=>this.httpService2.get())$,

  someUserAction2$
      .startWith(null)
      .switchMap(()=>this.httpService2.get())$
);
```